# I'm trying to solve, Advent of Code Day 17 Part 2. I get the correct answer to Part 1 but when i modified to solve P2 I get the wrong answer for input

Tags: python, graph-theory, dijkstra, path-finding, a-star

I'm a bit annoyed as to why my answer is wrong because, it passes the outputs for the test cases they have provided. Here is the link to the problem https://adventofcode.com/2023/day/17

Can anyone try to suggest me what I'm doing wrong here. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong since everything seems to be correct.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from heapq import heappush, heappop

pInput = [
    [int(char) for char in list(line.replace("\n", ""))]
    for line in open("input.txt", "r")
]
width, height = len(pInput[0]), len(pInput)


def maxStepsReached(steps):
    return steps > 10


def isOOB(y, x):
    return not (0 <= y < len(pInput) and 0 <= x < len(pInput[0]))


def expand_helper(node, dy, dx, dir, res):
    new_y = node[1] + dy
    new_x = node[2] + dx
    if isOOB(new_y, new_x) or dir == node[3] and maxStepsReached(node[4] + 1):
        return res
    if dir == node[3]:
        res.append((node[0] + pInput[new_y][new_x], new_y, new_x, dir, node[4] + 1))
    elif node[4] >= 4:
        res.append((node[0] + pInput[new_y][new_x], new_y, new_x, dir, 1))
    return res


def expand(node):
    res = []
    if node[3] == ">":
        for dy, dx, dir in [[0, 1, ">"], [-1, 0, "A"], [1, 0, "V"]]:
            res = expand_helper(node, dy, dx, dir, res)
    elif node[3] == "<":
        for dy, dx, dir in [[0, -1, "<"], [-1, 0, "A"], [1, 0, "V"]]:
            res = expand_helper(node, dy, dx, dir, res)
    elif node[3] == "A":
        for dy, dx, dir in [[-1, 0, "A"], [0, 1, ">"], [0, -1, "<"]]:
            res = expand_helper(node, dy, dx, dir, res)
    elif node[3] == "V":
        for dy, dx, dir in [[1, 0, "V"], [0, 1, ">"], [0, -1, "<"]]:
            res = expand_helper(node, dy, dx, dir, res)
    return res


def ucs():
    closed = set()
    open = []
    heappush(open, (0, 0, 0, ">", 1))

    while open:
        node = heappop(open)
        if node[1] == height - 1 and node[2] == width - 1 and node[4] >= 4:
            return node[0]
        if (node[1], node[2], node[3], node[4]) in closed:
            continue
        closed.add((node[1], node[2], node[3], node[4]))
        successors = expand(node)
        for s in successors:
            heappush(open, s)

    return -1


print(ucs())
```

Comment: For what it's worth, your code produces the correct result with my input.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you copied all 141 lines of your input text?

Comment: I directly downloaded the file. I re-downloaded multiple times too and no luck

Comment: Are you willing to email me your input, timr at probo dot com?

Comment: I sent it to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it.  The problem is your initial conditions.  You push the (0,0) point on your stack in all possible directions with an initial count of 1, but that's not correct.  When we start out, we don't COUNT that initial square, so the initial count should be 0.

Change your initialization to:

```
    heappush(open, (0, 0, 0, ">", 0))
```

and it all works.

So, why does matter?  Because your code allows us to consider a path that goes THREE from the origin, when in fact the requirement is to go FOUR from the origin.  My maze, for example, does not have that shorter path.

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from collections import namedtuple

Node = namedtuple('Node',['score','y','x','dir','c'])

pInput = [[int(char) for char in list(line.replace("\n", ""))] for line in open("day17.txt", "r")]
width, height = len(pInput[0]), len(pInput)

def isOOB(y, x):
   return not (y in range(height) and x in range(width))

alldirs = ((0,1,'>'), (1,0,'V'), (0,-1,'<'), (-1,0,'A'))
opposite = {a:b for a,b in zip('<>AV','><VA')}

MIN,MAX = (1,3)
MIN,MAX = (4,10)

def expand(node):
    for dy, dx, dir in alldirs:
        if opposite[node.dir] == dir:
            continue
        if dir != node.dir and node.c < MIN:
            continue
        new_y = node.y + dy 
        new_x = node.x + dx 
        if isOOB(new_y, new_x):
            continue
        if dir == node.dir:
            if node.c < MAX:
                yield Node(node.score + pInput[new_y][new_x], new_y, new_x, dir, node.c + 1)
        else:
            yield Node(node.score + pInput[new_y][new_x], new_y, new_x, dir, 1)


def ucs():
    closed = set()
    open = []
    heappush(open, Node(0, 0, 0, '>', 0))
    heappush(open, Node(0, 0, 0, 'V', 0))

    while open:
        node = heappop(open)
        if node.y == height - 1 and node.x == width - 1 and node.c >= MIN: 
            return node.score
        if node[1:] in closed:
            continue
        closed.add(node[1:])
        for s in expand(node):
            heappush(open, s)

    return -1

print(ucs())
```

Note that my version lets you do either part 1 or part 2 by commenting out one of the MIN/MAX lines.

Comment: Wow ur a saviour. I assumed that the first square is counted too. The wording on the question was a bit off i guess.